# How do I setup a reverse DNS entry in Plesk 9.2.2 frontent?

Tags: dns, plesk, reverse-dns

I need to get a reverse DNS entry into my zones file for one of my domains hosted under Plesk 9.2.2. Does anybody have ANY idea how this done? If all else fails I will have to update the zones file myself, but I am not sure how that will affect the front end working.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

The reverse DNS entries are actually held by the people who manage the IP address space for the server, so typically they will need to make this change.

Lets say your IP address is 1.2.3.4, and you want to set up a reverse DNS record, what will actually be queried is 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa, which will return a PTR record, which would be a domain, or sub-domain with an A record that matches 1.2.3.4.

If you talk to the people who manage your IP addresses, they should have this configured to respond to PTR records.

Comment: I manage the DNS entries myself. I was wondering if there was a way to do this via the front end of Plesk. I can update the zone files myself but would prefer to do it via the front end.